# No existe el fichero gradlew.bat en mi proyecto android, ¿Como generar el fichero gradlew.bat de nuevo?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, gradle

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\raul\Desktop\flutterWorkspace\meetn-mobile\android/gradlew.bat''
Could not start 'C:\Users\raul\Desktop\flutterWorkspace\meetn-mobile\android/gradlew.bat'
Cannot run program "C:\Users\raul\Desktop\flutterWorkspace\meetn-mobile\android/gradlew.bat" (in directory "C:\Users\raul\Desktop\flutterWorkspace\meetn-mobile\android"): CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Comment: Puede ser que el problema sea la barra de `/gradlew.bat` ??  El resto de barras de las rutas son barras invertidas o contrabarras.  O quizás es que simplemente esta ruta está mal:  `C:\Users\raul\Desktop\flutterWorkspace\meetn-mobile\android\gradlew.bat`.  ¿Lo has verificado en tu disco si está ahí?

Comment: Si realmente no existe y necesitas generarlo en [este enlace](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) explican algo al respecto

Answer (score 0):

Abre tu archivo `gradle-wrapper.properties` y obtén la `distributionUrl`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1-bin.zip
```

ahora en la terminal ejecuta el siguiente comando con la url de tu distribución gradle:

```
.\gradle wrapper --gradle-distribution-url https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1-bin.zip
```

Esto provocará que se genere nuevamente el archivo `gradlew.bat`.

De otra forma, si no tienes definida una url, puedes simplemente usar la versión que usas en tu proyecto:

```
.\gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.1
```